# How to print top 5 scores from a text file

Tags: sorting

I have an external text file where I store names and scores in the form:

> (name) has (score - integer) points

An example would be:

> Bob has 25 points

I would like to print the lines as they are but only  in descending order from highest score.

In other words, I would like to print the same lines as they are in the text file, but sorted from highest to lowest integer(score) in the line. I would also like to limit the printed lines, so that would mean only the scores in descending order are printed.

I have tried many ways but all I could end up with is separated names and scores which have quotes and parenthesis, but what I am aiming for is to print the lines as they are.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. In the future please provide a [mre] including input data, expected output, actual output, and an explanation about why your current code doesn't meet your needs. See [ask] for other advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly sort the lines, using the score as a key for `sort`:

```
path = "leaderboard.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()

file_lines.sort(key=lambda line: int(line.split()[2]), reverse=True)

print(''.join(file_lines[:5]))
```

Comment: Sorry, but you can't do that on SO, so I rolled the question back to its original state :)

Comment: @Mark You can't delete anything, the code is still visible in revision history of your post. Only mods can do this in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Thierry, the lines in `file_lines` are already `'\n` terminated, join them using `''.join(...`